# How to add new functionalities to Array types with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to migrate my code from regular js to webpack.

In the past, I have added new functionalities for the default `Array` or `Object` types, which I then used in my code. I would like to keep these new functionalities global in webpack also. How could I tell webpack, for example, to modify the `Array` type, and add the new functionality it, in every file, without importing this line of code every time I want to use it?

This is how I've done it in the past:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From webpack [Shimming Globals docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/):

We don't recommend using globals! The whole concept behind webpack is to allow more modular front-end development. This means writing isolated modules that are well contained and do not rely on hidden dependencies (e.g. globals). Please use these features only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your new prototype functionalities like `Array.prototype.clean` at top the of your defined webpack entry, probably `index.js`.

So there will be available for your whole project.

if you have multiple entry file,
you can create a file `prototype.js` with all your prototypes and put it as first entry file.

Comment: Okay, but what if I have multiple entries, one for each page? Can't I just put it somewhere globally, so I do not have to copy it into every entry file?